# Ex + sisto preposition choice

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, etymology, ancient-greek, language-evolution

Why is it exsisto instead of subsisto?

Between the verbs sisto and ἵστημι there seems to be an almost perfect correspondence in meaning but the prepositions switch from exsisto to ὑφίστημι (which seems to be in an almost perfect corresponsance too) and ἐξίστημι seems to have a totally different meaning.

How does the meaning of sisto change depending on the preceding preposition?